# map output from json array in GO

Tags: go

I need to create a map from a Json array , I started with below in GO , kind of stuck , any pointers ?

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    jsonStr := `{
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": 14325,
      "grpname": "senior"
    },
    {
      "id": 234,
      "grpname": "junior"
    }
  ]
}`

    type Group struct {
        Employee []struct {
            GroupName string
            GroupId   int
        }
    }

    var group []Group

    var groupMap []map[string]interface{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &groupMap)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, groupData := range groupMap {

        // convert map to array of Group struct
        var g Group
        g.GroupName = fmt.Sprintf("%s", groupData["grpname"])
        g.GroupId, _ = strconv.Atoi(fmt.Sprintf("%v", groupData["id"]))
        group = append(group, g)

    }
    fmt.Println(group)

}
```

Error:

```
./prog.go:45:4: g.GroupName undefined (type Group has no field or method GroupName)
./prog.go:46:4: g.GroupId undefined (type Group has no field or method GroupId)
```

Output expected:

```
{"senior": 14325,"junior": 234}
```

Tried few things like below , but getting error : There was an error:%!(EXTRA string=json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field GetEmpResponse.employee of type map[string][]model.Employee)

type GetEmpResponse struct {
Employee map[string][]Employee `json:"employee"`
}

***Tried to simplify the Json for my testing , please refer to*** [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/wvWzHuOGr-J)

Comment: You unmarshaling is correct. You cannot access `empresponse.Employee.ID` because `Employee` is an array. Write a for-loop to access `empresponse.Employee[i].ID`

Comment: @BurakSerdar I tried below , but still getting error

log.Printf("EmployeeId. :", empResponse.Employee[0].ID)

invalid operation: empResponse.Employee[0] (type model.Employee does not support indexing)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/wvWzHuOGr-J

Comment: Your data structure doesn't match the code. `g` does not have a `GroupName`. `g.Employee[i]` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empResponse.Employee` is an array, so you have to access its elements by index, e.g.

```
empResponse.Employee[0].ID
```